# Strange error appears when interfacing DHT and ESP8266 - Data is incessantly Changing Type

Tags: arduino, esp8266

When attempting to use a DHT11 module, an ESP8266 chip, and a standard FTDI chip to send temperature and humidity data to a database, I stumbled upon this strange error when uploading my program to the module:

```
esptool v0.4.8 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to ck
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from COM1 to COM20
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 9C instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 27847 bytes of data
    serialport_receive_C0: 62 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 03 instead of C0
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: C7 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 1B instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 03 instead of C0
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 1C instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 539 bytes of data
    serialport_receive_C0: 62 instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: C7 instead of C0
```

The code verifies fine, however, I believe it is a hardware issue.

Comment: Formatted log output as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a lower baudrate, it might be more stable.
You might also want to try a CP2102 based serial interface, it seems a lot of people have trouble with the FTDI ones.

Comment: I tried all variations on the baud rate and it outputted the same. Unfortunately, I have to use an FTDI.

Comment: That's unfortunate :) What is your wiring like? You're not powering the ESP from the FTDI are you? If you do you could try giving the ESP it's own power supply, only keep GND connected. It might also help to add some capacitors. Just in case there's a software issue, you could also actually add the command you're using, instead of only the output, and you could try a different flash tool, for example try just the Espressif flash tool, and the AT firmware from their SDK.